# Docker Swarm error - invalid mount config for type

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

This is my Docker compose/stack file. When I deploy on a single node, everything works fine, but when I deploy on multiple nodes I get the following error:

> invalid mount config for type bind bind source path does not exist

```
version: '3'
services:
  shinyproxy:
    build: /etc/shinyproxy
    deploy: 
      replicas: 3
    user: root:root
    hostname: shinyproxy
    image: shinyproxy-example
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks: 
      - proxynetwork
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    deploy: 
      replicas: 3    
    volumes:
      - /mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks: 
      - proxynetwork
  keycloak:
    deploy: 
      replicas: 3  
    image: jboss/keycloak
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/privkey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
      #- /theme/govuk-social-providers/:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/govuk-social-providers/
    environment:
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=myadmin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=mypassword
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    networks: 
      - proxynetwork

networks:
  proxynetwork:
    external: true
```

I understand that the volumes path is expected on every other node too, but I think this is a very bad practice and my other 2 nodes are anyway just workers. How can I solve that problem? Hopefully there is a solution which allows me to keep the volumes, since I use the same file for `docker-compose build` to build my images.

Can someone help me?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Having a dependency on host volumes is not ideal in this case. I would suggest creating a `Dockerfile` and copy the certs and theme during build. Then simply add that to the yml.

Answer (score 5):

If it is possible you could restrict this service to the node that has the required host path's using [placement constraints](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#placement). However I'm guessing that that's not an option in this use case.
Host mounted volumes should really not be used in a swarm deployment as it would cause redundant data in the filesystems between the nodes. (All files need to be present on all nodes).

One solution would be to implement [NFS volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#driver_opts):

```
volumes:
  example:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=<NFS_SERVER_IP>,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/docker/path/to/configs"
```

This solution requires you to host a NFS-Server though. Also keep in mind that this approach is fine for configs but should not be used for file systems that need to provide high performance access.

Regarding your question about keeping your docker-compose file the same across environments: While it is technically possible to do so, most modern projects consist of a base compose file as well as an environment specific override for volumes,networks,images etc.

Answer (score 0):

In a swarm your services will be deployed randomly on your available nodes.
I suppose your "to be mounted directory" is on the manager node, so deploy the wanted service on the manager node like so.

```
deploy:
    placement:
        constraints:
            - node.role == manager
```